# htaccess change url conteining dots with -

Tags: .htaccess

I'm dealing with URL's that contains dots in htaccess. I wish to change them by '-'.

Let's say I have this URL: http://www.example.com/1.0version/

So, i would like that htaccess could change it in the following way:

http://www.example.com/1-0version/

I've been reading some other topics here and no success.

Any idea?

Comment: Maybe take a look at RewriteMap? https://devdocs.io/apache_http_server/mod/mod_rewrite#rewritemap

Comment: Or, if your patterns are consistent; writing a small RewriteRule pattern will not be difficult

Comment: @hjpotter92 I'm completly lost in this topic!